# How i know if a inflate view exist

Tags: android, layout-inflater

When i press a button i want that a inflate view appear and when i press the same button this view disappear...

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.inflate_place);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_find, null);

for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = parent.getChildAt(i);

    // Here i want that if is the same layout, this disappear
    if (nextChild.equals(view)) { 
        parent.removeView(nextChild);
        return;
    }
}

parent.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-inflating the same view over and over again is not the best approach usually.

Just add a variable to your Activity that points to the view you want to hide:

```
View myView;
```

In onCreate, inflate your view:

```
myView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_find, null);
```

Now, if you want to show the view, you could just add it as in your existing code:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.inflate_place);
parent.add(myView);
```

Removing could be done like that:

```
If (myView.getParent()!=null){
   ((ViewGroup) myView.getParent()).removeView(myView);
}
```

Toggling the view's visibility would work like that:

```
If (myView.getParent()!=null){
   ((ViewGroup) myView.getParent()).removeView(myView);
} else {
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.inflate_place);
   parent.add(myView);
}
```

You might want to have a look at View.setVisibility(). That's what is usually used for showing and hiding a view: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

You can check from ViewGroup indexOfChild(View view) method if the child is exist or not. it returns a positive integer representing the position of the view in the group, or -1 if the view does not exist in the group

```
    ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) getWindow().peekDecorView();
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View myView= li.inflate(R.layout.recorder, null);
    if(rootLayout.indexOfChild(myView) == -1)
        rootLayout.addView(myView);
```